# NHibernate - Eager loading grouped object when aggregating

Tags: nhibernate, aggregate, eager-loading

I have the following code where I am aggregating auction statistics from a statistics table and returning the Auction as well as the summed counts (there may be multiple rows in the statistics table per auction...)

```
   var stats = _session.QueryOver<AuctionStatistic>()
       .Select(
           Projections.Group<AuctionStatistic>(s => s.Auction),
           Projections.Sum<AuctionStatistic>(s => s.BidCount),
           Projections.Sum<AuctionStatistic>(s => s.ViewCount),
           Projections.Sum<AuctionStatistic>(s => s.SearchCount)
       )
       .OrderBy(Projections.Sum<AuctionStatistic>(s => s.ApplicationCount)).Desc
       .Fetch(x => x.Auction).Eager
       .Take(take)
       .List<object[]>();
```

The query itself seems to work fine - except that the Auction that is returned is evaluated lazily, causing a SELECT N+1 scenario. Can anyone provide suggestions as to how this field can be evaluated eagerly?

Thanks in advance

JP

Answer (score 0):

The brute force way would be (similar to a sub-select):

```
_session.QueryOver<Auction>().WhereRestrictionOn(a => a.Id).IsIn(stats.SelectMany(s => s).OfType<Auction>().Select(a => a.Id).ToArray());
```

Comment: But this doesn't bring back my stats, it just brings back the auctions themselves...right?

Comment: It puts the Auctions into the 1st level cache - avoiding your SELECT N+1 issue when you access your Auctions. You should run that query just after the first one. Notice that I don't put the result into anything - essentially only putting them into the cache for later access.